# Meaning of "for good and often for ill"

Tags: meaning

I came across this statement:

> "Both Plato and Aristotle speak of music as "imitating" or "representing" the characters and passionate tones of men, but seem to suggest that the end for which this imitation exists is for the arousal of such passions in the listener, for good (Aristotle) and often for ill (Plato).

(from *[The Harvard Dictionary of Music](https://books.google.com/books?id=02rFSecPhEsC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=for+good+(Aristotle)+and+often+for+ill+(Plato)&source=bl&ots=Ul8XNLXhLL&sig=a12Qfjrz5txLe9zo9hTza5qpYL0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm5LjkwtvMAhUMUVIKHd55BNgQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=for%20good%20(Aristotle)%20and%20often%20for%20ill%20(Plato)&f=false),* by Don Michael Randel)

What does it mean, specifically "for good (Aristotle) and often for ill (Plato)"?

Comment: Both Plato and Aristotle speak of music as "imitating" or "representing" the characters and passionate tones of men, but seem to suggest that the end for which this imitation or representation exists is the arousal of such passions in the listener, for good (Aristotle) and often for ill (Plato).

Comment: "for good (Aristotle) and often for ill (Plato)"

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate constructions here that you may not be familiar with: the "[…] (Aristotle) […] (Plato)" construction, and the "for good […] for ill" construction.

---

### […] (Aristotle) […] (Plato)

The sentence is largely about something where Aristotle and Plato agree, but it also mentions one point on which they disagree. The "[…] (Aristotle) […] (Plato)" construction lets the author indicate which philosopher holds which position on the point where they disagree: Aristotle believes the arousal is "for good", Plato believes it is "often for ill".

Furthermore, in your sentence, the author is using this construction as the *only* indication that the two philosophers disagree on this point; without the *(Aristotle)* and *(Plato)*, not only would it be unclear which philosopher held which view, but it wouldn't even be clear that two contrasting views were being described.

Incidentally, this construction is not necessarily restricted to cases of disagreement; it can be used for any sort of contrast. For example, I might write:

> On St. Patrick's Day, most students wore either green (Catholic) or orange (Protestant), but a few wore black (Gothic).

---

### for good […] for ill

The phrase *for good or ill*, [according to Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/for-good-or-ill), means:

> whether the effect will be good or bad
>   *He felt he wanted to remain on the team, for good or ill.*

Your sentence, of course, has a slightly different phrasing — "for good (Aristotle) and often for ill (Plato)" — but the idea is the same: "for good" means "with good effect", "for ill" means "with bad effect".

(Note: "for good" and "for ill" are *not* usually used separately. Your sentence pairs them a bit differently from how they're usually paired, but the important thing is that they're still used together, so that the contrast is clear.)

---

So, overall, the author is saying that Aristotle views music's arousal of passions as having a good effect, whereas Plato views it as often having a bad effect.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Aristotle saw the goal of music as arousing or reinforcing positive feelings (e.g.; happiness, contentment) in its listeners, while Plato saw it as arousing or reinforcing negative feelings (e.g.; anger, sadness).

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The difference is in the two philosophers' attitudes toward emotion in general, not in their opinions about which emotions are aroused by music.

Comment: You may be right.